# Calculate statistically difference between given values

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
```

Having a tibble with values (these values express differences in mean air time)

```
  origin mean_air_time
 <chr>      <dbl>
1 EWR         153.
2 JFK         178.
3 LGA         118.
```

**How can I in R find out if these differences are statistically different?**

What I tried doing is (adding an extra col with mean to the flights):

```
mutation <- flights %>%
 group_by(origin) %>% 
 mutate(meanAir_time = mean(air_time, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Now trying to create a linear model using the data with the new col

```
value <- lm(dep_time ~ meanAir_time, data = mutation)
```

Finally showing the result:

```
coef(summary(lModel))

Estimate Std. Error   t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  1135.064406 5.33534358 212.74439        0
meanAir_time    1.420515 0.03495606  40.63716        0
```

I am very concerned with the result `Pr(>|t|)` Seeing that this result `> 5%` I would say that there is a significant difference, however, I fear I am doing it right. I'm not sure wether I should use the `dep_time` in the `lm(...)`

Comment: You should just need `lm(air_time ~ origin, data = flights)`, linear model w 3 level factor compares the group means, then you could do pairwise comparisons. You should not calculate the means and then stick them into an lm. In the future, for modeling questions you're better off over at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Also, there are over 100,000 observations in each group, so any mean differences are likely to show up statistically significant. Statistical significance isn't always the most interesting comparison